# Set default tab in ionic2

Tags: ionic2

On my login page I am using `this.nav.setRoot(TabsPage);` to navigate to the 'main app'. However, this makes the first tab the default page. On the other hand, if i use `this.nav.setRoot(HomePage)`; I get the correct page but am missing the tabs. How do I set the default tab on page switch?

Comment: Instead of adding the solution to the OP, please add it as an answer so other users can find how to solve this easier :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After further googling, I found the solution in the ionic2 documents. If anyone else in the future is wondering the same thing, the solution is to add `selectedIndex="X"` to the `<ion-tabs>` tag. (http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/tabs/Tabs/)

UPDATE for clarity: 
your code will look like this for selecting the 3rd tab:

`<ion-tabs selectedIndex="2">`

and like this fore selecting the 2nd tab:

`<ion-tabs selectedIndex="1">`

Comment: works but the first one is "0" not "1" and for those who want to change it dynamically you have to BIND to a local var [selectedIndex]="defaultTab"